# Not finding the last Column in Excel Correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, where I am copy-pasting a table from one Excel file to another and then I want to compare the tables and later use this information. However, my loop doesn't iterate through the whole table column, because as it turns out, the count of the columns is incorrect. I am not sure why, could it be, because I am pasting one of the tables, and maybe there is like a delay?? Any help would be appreciated. I want to compare one cell of the first table column with the whole of the second table column etc...

```
' Paste data into existing workbook
Dim existingSheet As Worksheet
Set existingSheet = existingWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim pasteRange As Range
Set pasteRange = existingSheet.Range("J18")


selectedTable.Range.Copy pasteRange

Dim lastColumnB As Long
lastColumnB = existingSheet.Cells(18, existingSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlDown).Column

Dim lastColumnJ As Long
lastColumnJ = existingSheet.Cells(18, existingSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlDown).Column

' Compare the values of column B with column J
Dim cellB As Range
Dim cellJ As Range
Dim matchingCellsCount As Integer
matchingCellsCount = 0
Dim nonMatchingCellsCount As Integer
nonMatchingCellsCount = 0

For i = 2 To lastColumnB
Set cellB = existingSheet.Cells(18, i)
Set cellJ = existingSheet.Cells(18, i + (lastColumnJ - lastColumnB))

If cellB.Value = cellJ.Value Then
matchingCellsCount = matchingCellsCount + 1
Else
nonMatchingCellsCount = nonMatchingCellsCount + 1
End If
Next i

Cells
MsgBox "Number of matching cells: " & matchingCellsCount & vbNewLine & "Number of non-matching cells: " & nonMatchingCellsCount & vbNewLine & "Last J Column " & lastColumnJ & vbNewLine & "Last B Column " & lastColumnB
```

Comment: use xlToLeft `lastColumnB = existingSheet.Cells(18, existingSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: That method of finding the last column - even with the fix - will not work with jagged data - so also check you have no gaps in the headers

Comment: @CHill60 yeah it doesn't, I think its just the tables I am working with. I had to hardcode it  so that I chose specific cells. However now I am trying to add a row of data to the table and it won't let me shift cells from the table

Comment: I can't comment on the table because you haven't shared any data. You should also explain what you mean by "it won't let me shift cells from the table" - to get the best help here, clearly explain what happens

Answer (score 0):

To get the last column from a worksheet use this code and adjust it according to your need ( I am sure it will work with jagged data also):

```
Dim lastColumnB As Long
lastColumnB = existingSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column
```